# eBay API revise store categories beyond root level

Tags: ebay-api

The eBay API documentation says regarding the eBay Store category:

> A custom category is a category that the seller created in their eBay
>   Store. eBay Store sellers can create up to three levels of custom
>   categories for their stores, but the API only supports root-level
>   categories.

Really? Is there no way to add a listing via the API with a eBay Store category below the first level. In my case I'm trying to revise the Store categories of existing items and they all will be to the below level.

The structure is very simple, basically like this:

```
North

-North East

-North West


South

-South East

-South West
```

I want to put everything into one of the subcategories. Can the API support this? Any other way? FileExchange perhaps?

[ebay api](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/ReviseFixedPriceItem.html#Request.Item.Storefront.StoreCategoryID)

Answer (score 0):

You can list to any store category at any level, up to three, provided the category does not have any child categories.

Given the category structure below:

```
|-- Comics
|    |
|    |-- Marvel
|    |-- DC
|
|-- DVDs
|
|-- Blu Ray
|
|-- Audio Books
|    |
|    |-- Fiction
|    |    |
|    |    |-- Abridged
|    |    |-- Unabridged
|    |
|    |-- Non Fiction
```

The categories you can list to are:

- Marvel
- DC
- DVDs
- Blu Ray
- Abridged
- Unabridged
- Non Fiction